# TestCases field on TestSet object is empty

Tags: rally

I wrote a Rally app to do reporting on TestSets and TestCases. Suddenly today, my app was not getting any TestCases in it's query.

To simplify this, I will take my app out of the equation and I am just running queries with the web service api: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/index.jsp?version=1.40

If I query a TestSet, the TestCases field, which should contain a list of the TestCases in the TestSet, is coming back empty for TestSets that definitely have TestCases. This was working perfectly up until sometime in the last few days (we used the app today and weren't getting any TestCases when the last time we used it, we were and no changes have occurred on our end).

If I look at Test Cases in Track->Iteration Status in Rally and expand the TestSet to see all the TestCases, they show up. So they are there, just for some reason the web service api isn't returning them.

I've spent the last two hours reading the API documentation and searching Google to see if anyone else has had this issue or if anything might have changed that is causing this, but I haven't found anything.

I have confirmed that other objects containing a list of TestCase objects (such as TestFolders) are properly returning a list of TestCases. I have also confirmed that I am able to query the individual TestCases that should be returned in the list. I have also confirmed that I am able to query the TestCaseResult for the particular TestSet and TestCase.

So I am really stumped. It appears as though it's just TestSet.TestCases that isn't working and I am unable to find any specific cause or correlate something unrelated that could be the cause.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I can confirm that this is happening in my subscription, too.  I think it is a bug that you should report through the Contact Support link at the bottom of any Rally UI page.

Comment: This affects our custom tools too.

Answer (score 2):

Rally's DevOps team issued a fix for this issue the evening of 10-jan-2013. TestSet queries through WSAPI should be appropriately hydrated with member TestCases again. Contact [Rally Support](http://www.rallydev.com/open-support-case) with any questions or concerns.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug - Rally's engineering team is aware of the problem and is working on a fix. Please file a Case with [Rally Support](http://www.rallydev.com/open-support-case) to report/get status updates on the Defect resolution.